# Forward generated token to microservices

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

How can I tell to the Zuul APi gateway to forward the token (JWT generated by this last one) to the requested microservices.
Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Zuul -> Eureka Server, Basic Authentication issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102980/zuul-eureka-server-basic-authentication-issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in: [Zuul -> Eureka Server, Basic Authentication issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39102980/zuul-eureka-server-basic-authentication-issue/39119381#39119381)

```
zuul.sensitiveHeaders: Cookie,Set-Cookie
```